# calling javascript function on mouse release Jquery UI draggable

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to drag divs around a container and i want to fire an event when the user releases the mouse (stops dragging).

Any ideas on how to do this would be great. Thanks in advance

-Shawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI, you have a built in function already:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#event-stop

```
$('.selector').draggable({
     stop: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

If you're not using the Draggable function from the UI, I'd recommend you do so. It will make your life easier for this!  It's already written!

Comment: Can you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148384/jquery-ui-draggable-does-not-call-custom-function ?