# jQuery ui.draggable does not Call custom Function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I have a javascript function showAlert(). There is a draggable image. After the drag is stopped, we need to show the alert. Its not working How do we correct it?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui.draggable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () 
        {

            $("#d1").draggable(
            {

                drag: function (event, ui) 
                {
                },

                stop: function (event, ui) 
                {
                    showAlert();
                },

                cursor: "move"

            });

        });

        function showAlert() 
        {
            alert("hai");
        }



    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="border:2px solid orange; width:500px; height:300px;"  >
    <br />
        <img src="MyIMages/RedSquare.jpg" alt="" id="d1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with the jquery UI libraries and it worked http://jsfiddle.net/5HyyP/

Comment: Yes, I saw it working in your jsfiddle.net code. Strange. Why is it not working in my scenario when I run it from Visual Studio?

Comment: The only difference is, I used the JS libraries from the CDN, check your JS files or check on ur browsers JS console to find if anything errors out.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I used CDN src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js".

Comment: And jsFiddle is a great new knowledge to me. I very much liked it.

Answer (score 1):

The image is run on server, so the render ID is different, and the script not found it to use it: Change the javascript

```
$("#<%=d1.ClientID%>").draggable(
        {
```

OR change the image, remove the run=server

```
<img src="MyIMages/RedSquare.jpg" alt="" id="d1" />
```

Comment: I tired both the approaches. Both of them did not work. Did u try it yourself?

Comment: @Lijo Try also to load it after the page load.