# Get coordinates of body on drag of element using jQuery ui library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

On Drag and drop of div I want to get coordinates of dragged div (Coordinate should be left, right and top) I also want to post those coordinates using ajax. 
example link 
jsfiddle.net/qPw92

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
        .draggable { 
            width: 150px; 
            min-height: 150px; 
            padding: 0.5em; 
            border:1px solid black; 
            overflow-wrap: break-word; 
         }
         </style>
         <script>   
         $(function() {             
             $('.draggable').draggable({
                 var data={ 
                     // Get some dives coordinates 
                 };
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/index.php/pages/getinfo/",
                     data: data,
                     type: 'POST',
                     success: function(result){
                         //alert(result);
                         $("#ajaxResponce").html(result);
                     }
                 });
             });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
        <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
        <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <p>Drag me around</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, what is the problem you're having with your code? Secondly, please take the time to format your code so it's readable in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add a callback for the Draggable event:

```
$('.move').draggable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
            x = offset.left,
            y = offset.top;
        $(this).text("Position: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    }
});
```

Here, when the draggable object stops being dragged, it gets the x and y position and sets the text to that. You can see a demo of that here: http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/vKwFj/.

In order to send that as an AJAX call, just write a function where you can specify the x and y position:

```
function sendToDB(x, y){
    var data = JSON.stringify({"x": x, "y": y});
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax URL",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(result){
            // Do something here
        });
    });
});
```

And then we just call that function in our stop callback. Another demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/3Lx7z/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

So you have to use this options. `position()` or `offset()`.

`position()` Basically similar to what you could use in the CSS top, left properties.

`offset()` Will return the distance relative to the document. This considers margins, paddings, and borders.

`$('#id').offset()`

Refer

http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: the main problem is even simple alert is not work in dragge able how can i send ajax request 
any event you know of draggebale 
 $('.draggable').draggable({ alert();});

Comment: refer this your function must be like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148384/jquery-ui-draggable-does-not-call-custom-function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qPw92/
i want to get left ,top, and right then send them ajax request

Comment: try with this `$(".draggable" ).on( "drag", function( event, ui ) {
         
         alert('hi')
     });`

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qPw92/1/ console log working